# read only some columns with RSQLite?

Tags: r, dplyr, rsqlite

I only want to read 3 columns from a table. Right now I'm doing something that I guess is very inefficient

```
library(dplyr, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)
library(RSQLite, quietly = T) 
db <- dbConnect( SQLite() , "SIPP08.db" )
dbListTables(db) 
w13 <- dbReadTable( db , 'w13' )
dbDisconnect(db)

df = w13 %>%
  select(ssuid, epppnum,ejbind1)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

---

I also tried using dplyr like this

```
my_db <- src_sqlite(path = "SIPP08.db")
w13 <- tbl(my_db, "w13")
df = w13 %>%
  select(ssuid, epppnum,ejbind1)
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to directly query the SQLite DB, something along these lines

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

db <- src_sqlite("SIPP08.db")
df <- tbl(db, sql("SELECT ssuid, epppnum, ejbind1 from wt13"))
```

I don't why you have a `list` but you can just use the `DBI` package and `RSQLite` to have a `data.frame`

```
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite() , "SIPP08.db")
df <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT ssuid, epppnum, ejbind1 from wt13")
```

I don't have your data but the first code works for me using a toy dataset.

Comment: I get an error: 
    Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"

Comment: @Ignacio strange! I added another way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Oh I see now, but I think it would best to do `src_sqlite("SIPP08.db") %>% tbl("wt13") %>% select(ssuid, epppnum, ejbind1)`

Comment: @hadley There is probably something missing in his installation because this code doesn't work for him. He tried it (see second attempt with dplyr in the question) but without further information on why, its really difficult to help.